# JQuery selectable functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help me with my js selector functions?  The problem is the color and size indicator numbers showing do not default back to "blank" after mouseout. I want the indicator number to disappear after mouseout if a mouseclick never happens over the function.  Can anyone help?  My demo http://jsfiddle.net/jwjxr2oh/3/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when `sizeIndicator.data('selected')` is not present `sizeIndicator.data('selected')` will return undefined, then the `text()` method will act like a getter method and will not update the value to blank so

```js
$(function() {
  var colorsList = $('#colors');
  var sizesList = $('#sizes');
  var colorIndicator = $('#color_indicator');
  var sizeIndicator = $('#size_indicator');

  var colors = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dark Blue Denim',
    color: '#0B3861'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Light Blue Denim',
    color: '#81BEF7'
  }];
  var sizes = [{
    id: 1,
    name: '26'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: '28'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: '30'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: '32'
  }];

  $.each(colors, function() {
    colorsList.append(
      $('<li>').attr({
        id: 'color_' + this.id
      })
      .data('info', this)
      .append(
        $('<div>').css('background-color', this.color)));
  });

  $.each(sizes, function() {
    sizesList.append(
      $('<li>').attr({
        id: 'size_' + this.id
      })
      .data('info', this)
      .text(this.name)
      .addClass('text'));
  });

  colorsList.selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
      var total = $(ui.selected).siblings('li.ui-selected').length + 1;
      if (total > 1) {
        $(ui.selected).removeClass('ui-selected');
      } else {
        var color = $(ui.selected).data('info').name;
        colorIndicator.data('selected', color).text(color);
      }
    }
  });

  sizesList.selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
      var total = $(ui.selected).siblings('li.ui-selected').length + 1;
      if (total > 1) {
        $(ui.selected).removeClass('ui-selected');
      } else {
        var size = $(ui.selected).data('info').name;
        sizeIndicator.data('selected', size).text(size);
      }
    }
  });

  sizesList.children('li').hover(function() {
    sizeIndicator.text($(this).data('info').name);
  }, function() {
    console.log(sizeIndicator)
    sizeIndicator.text(sizeIndicator.data('selected') || '');
  });

  colorsList.children('li').hover(function() {
    colorIndicator.text($(this).data('info').name);
  }, function() {
    colorIndicator.text(colorIndicator.data('selected') || '');
  });

  $('#show').click(function() {
    var color = colorsList.find('li.ui-selected').eq(0).data('info');
    var size = sizesList.find('li.ui-selected').eq(0).data('info');

    if (typeof color != 'undefined') {
      alert('Color selected: ' + color.name + ', id: ' + color.id);
    }

    if (typeof size != 'undefined') {
      alert('Size selected: ' + size.name + ', id: ' + size.id);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 .selectable li.ui-selecting {} .selectable li.ui-selected {
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 .selectable {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .selectable li {
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   margin: 3px;
   padding: 3px;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .selectable li:hover {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 3px;
   padding: 3px;
   cursor: pointer;
   cursor: hand;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .selectable li div {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 3px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
 }
 .selectable li.text {
   color: #000;
   padding: .5em .5em;
   margin: .5em 1em;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   border-radius: 50%;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   line-height: 1em;
 }
 .selectable li.text:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   cursor: hand;
   color: #000;
   font-weight: normal;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='button' id='show' value='What is selected?'>
<table width="595" height="172" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="421" height="40" align="center" valign="middle">Size: <span id="size_indicator"></span>
    </td>
    <td width="164">Color: <span id="color_indicator"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="103">
      <ol id="sizes" class='selectable'></ol>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ol id="colors" class='selectable'></ol>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6v158aej/

Comment: It would have been nice if you have edited the question also. Instead of answering complete on fiddle reference.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now.  /thumbsup :)